# java map struct with DB spring boot jpa

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto, mapstruct

i have a DTOX and entityX entityX has an attribute entityY (one to one relation) and the DTOX has attribute entitiyYID (the id of the attached entityY to entityX)

is there any way to make the mapper be able to get the entityY form the DB and map it to the entityX while using the mapper to map between DTOX and entityX??

Answer (score 0):

I used the `@Aftermapping` annotation and add the implementation of getting the entity from the database and attaching it.

Note that you have to use `@Context` for each service you want to use, and you have to pass the service as an attribute to the mapper.